# Scala Builder Pattern: illegal cyclic reference involving type T

Tags: class, scala, generics, overriding

I'm trying to write some generic builders for my User class hierarchy.
I have a trait, UserBuilder and each "with" method in the trait has to return the same type as the current class. So if I'm inside the ComplexUserBuilder, the withId method should return a ComplexUserBuilder and not a UserBuilder.

But I'm getting

> illegal cyclic reference involving type T

Is there a way to workaround this?

Here is my code:

```
trait UserBuilder[T >: UserBuilder[T]] {

  var id: String = ""

  def withId(id: String): T = {
    this.id = id
    return this
  }
}

class ComplexUserBuilder extends UserBuilder[ComplexUserBuilder] {

  var username: String = ""

  def withUsername(username: String): ComplexUserBuilder = {
    this.username = username
    return this
  }

  def build = new ComplexUser(id, username)
}
```

By the way, if I replace `trait UserBuilder[T >: UserBuilder[T]]` with `trait UserBuilder[T >: UserBuilder[_]]` I get:

> type arguments [model.ComplexUserBuilder] do not conform to trait UserBuilder's type parameter bounds [T >: model.UserBuilder[_]]

Update:

```
trait UserBuilder[T >: UserBuilder[T]]
```

should be (as GClaramunt suggested)

```
trait UserBuilder[T <: UserBuilder[T]]
```

but now there is an ugly cast as the return type

Comment: I think you have your variance annotation the wrong way around.  Shouldn't it be `trait UserBuilder[T <: UserBuilder[T]] {`? (note `<:` vs `>:`)

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what are you trying to achieve? Where's the ComplexUser class?

Comment: the ComplexUser class is not relevant `case class ComplexUser(id: String, username: String)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make your `UserBuilder` subclasses have a reference to their own type, you should declare the type of `this` (and make them *sub*-types, not *super*-types, of `UserBuilder`):

```
trait UserBuilder[T <: UserBuilder[T]] { this: T =>
  ...
}
```

Comment: And this is not an answer to your original question, but I think it would be easier and better to make your builder objects immutable, and the `withX()` methods return new, immutable objects. `b = a.withId(...)` would look like you're using immutable objects, not like `a` would be changed. What do you gain by tricking people who see or use your code?

Comment: Ah, yes! I've tried that at the withId level but forgot to put it at the class level

Answer (score 4):

Dan has solved your problem pretty clear. What I want to say is, you even don't need the generic T at all, by using the this.type feature of scala.

```
trait UserBuilder {

  var id: String = ""

  def withId(id: String): this.type = {
    this.id = id
    return this
  }
}

class ComplexUserBuilder extends UserBuilder {

  var username: String = ""

  def withUsername(username: String): this.type = {
    this.username = username
    return this
  }

  def build = new ComplexUser(id, username)
}
```

And, if you want to add the build method to the UserBuilder trait, you may want to add a generic type U to constraint the user type, like

```
trait UserBuilder[U <: { def id: String }] {

  var id: String = ""

  def withId(id: String): this.type = {
    this.id = id
    return this
  }

  def build: U
}

class ComplexUserBuilder extends UserBuilder[ComplexUser] {

  var username: String = ""

  def withUsername(username: String): this.type = {
    this.username = username
    return this
  }

  def build = new ComplexUser(id, username)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve, but you have the upper type bound restriction backwards should be "<:" instead of ":>"

:> is a lower type bound restriction, meaning, T must be a super type of UserBuilder,  you want a subtype (so you can extend UserBuilder )

```
trait UserBuilder[T <: UserBuilder[T]] {
    self: T =>

    var id: String = ""

    def withId(id: String): T = {
      this.id = id
      this
    }
  }

  class ComplexUserBuilder extends UserBuilder[ComplexUserBuilder] {

    var username: String = ""

    def withUsername(username: String): ComplexUserBuilder = {
      this.username = username
      this
    }

    //def build = new ComplexUser(id, username)
  }
```

Also, you don't need "return", (almost) everything in Scala is an expression that returns a value.

Comment: This seems to work, but as you said, the `this.asInstanceOf[T]` is kind of ugly...